# How control email confirmations after creating folders and setting permissions

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a parent folder and then creating a bunch of child folders inside.

I am setting the permissions like:

```
var editor  = 'editors@example.com';
var owner   = 'owner@example.com';

var newProjectFolder = projectFolder.createFolder(projectNumber).addEditor(editor).setOwner(owner);

var child = newProjectFolder.createFolder('00 MEETINGS').addEditor(editor);   
// ...and some more child folders
```

How do I stop the child folders firing off confirmation emails? I would just prefer that the parent project folder was confirmed via email.

Thanks everyone,

Answer (score 0):

The child folders/files will automatically inherit the permissions of the parent, so you should not need to call "addEditor" on each item created within that parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the advanced Drive service.

```
var editor = Drive.newPermission();
editor.id = 'editors@example.com';
editor.role = 'writer';
Drive.Permissions.insert(editor, folderId, {"sendNotificationEmails":false});
```

Info on advanced services

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services

Info on drive advanced service

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive